# sed on mac: 'extra characters after p command'

Tags: regex, macos, sed

On Linux I use this to get the next two lines after the `[test]` line:

```
sed -n '/\[test\]/{n;p;n;p}' my-file
```

On Mac I get:

```
sed: 1: "/\\[test\\]/{n;p;n;p}": extra characters at the end of p command.
```

Is there an expression that works on both platforms or on Mac a completely different command must be used?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Add an extra semi-colon after the last `p`

```
 sed -n '/\[test\]/{n;p;n;p;}' my-file
```

(not related to Mac version, also fails on MSYS)

Answer (score 27):

Additionally, if you happen to get this error when using the `-i` option without an extension:

```sh
> sed -i 's/foo/bar/g' file
sed: 1: "file": extra characters at the end of p command
```

In this case the solution is to explicitly set the extension to an empty string:

```sh
> sed -i '' 's/foo/bar/g' file
```

Answer (score 6):

OSX (BSD) sed needs each command be terminated by `;` or on a separate line.

So this should work:

```
sed -n '/\[test\]/{n;p;n;p;}' my-file
```

Or even this one will work:

```
sed -n '/\[test\]/{
n
p
n
p
}' my-file
```